# $x^3+4x^2+ax+2$ ,a is constant, is denoted by p(x). Given, remainder when p(x) is ÷ by $(x+1)$ is = to remainder when p(x) is ÷ by $(x-2)$. Find a.

Tags: polynomials

Hello there fellow users. I would like to have some helping hand on how to approach this particular question, as i have recently started on polynomials. I am unable to comprehend on how to start it off. An approach to the answer would be grateful. Thanks in advance, and sorry for amy inconvenience!
P.s the first one is the polynomial

Comment: Hint: By the polynomial remainder theorem the question statement is equivalent to $$p(-1)=p(2)$$

Comment: I see.... I shall try it as such

Comment: It is confusing to use symbols like that (÷, =) in running text.

Comment: @TonyK really sorry about that, text limit?

Comment: Alas i reached the answer. Thanks peter foreman for the help. How do i uh... Close the thread?

Comment: Why alas? Surely that is good?

Comment: The first division gives remainder $-a+5$ and the second one gives $2a+24$. Since the two remainders are equal we get $a=\dfrac{-19}{3}$

Comment: If you find the answer for yourself, the nice thing to do is to post the answer yourself. You can then accept it.